# How to access opaque implementation of a class from an extern "C" friend function in C?

Tags: c++

In case the title doesn't quite make sense, here's a stripped-down example.  Consider this myclass.h:

```
// Compiled with g++ 4.7 and -std=c++0x -pedantic -Wall -Wextra on Linux
class myclass {
public:
    myclass()=default;
    void init();

private:
   struct myclassImpl;
   static myclassImpl _impl;
}`
```

and myclass.cpp

```
#include <csignal>
using namespace std;
#include "myclass.h"

extern "C" {   
    void end_sig(int);
}   

struct myclass::myclassImpl {
    friend void end_sig(int);

    myclassImpl()=default;
    void cleanup();
}   

myclass::myclassImpl myclass::_impl;

extern "C" {
    void end_sig(int /* sig */) {
        myclass::_impl.cleanup();
    }
}

void myclass::init() {
    signal (SIGINT, end_sig);
}

void myclass::myclassImpl::cleanup() {
    // stuff...
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to implement the bridge or pimpl pattern (and the monostate pattern though I don't think it is relevant to this particular problem.)  Mostly it works but in this particular implementation and not others, I have to make a signal handler which must be an extern "C" function not a method of the class.  If the code is set up like this, I get the following error:

```
In function ‘void end_sig(int)’:    
error: ‘myclass::myclassImpl myclass::_impl’ is private
```

I can think of two ways around this.

1. move the friend declaration into myclass.
2. make _impl public.

But in both cases it would violate the seperation of interface and implementation right?  Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: can't you have a getter that returns a pointer to the proc/func/method whatever term is appropriate in this context?

Comment: The friend statement in myClassImpl doesn't do anything if all members are already public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've done this, which I'd recommend, is to make `end_sig` a static method of `myclassImpl`.  It will have C linkage so can be passed to `signal`, and also have access to any necessary internals.  No need for a free friend function, and it's still hidden in the pimpl.

Comment: Thankyou!  I don't have enough reputation to vote you up but this suggestion works perfectly.  I did consider a static method initially but I assumed it might still have a this pointer or something that would make it unsuitable for passing to a C function.  I guess I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You're already tightly coupling your signal handler to your implementation, so I would just make it a friend of `myclass` as your option 1.

Another option is to make a public cleanup function in `myclass` and no friendship at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  There are a couple of different implementations and only this one would need the signal handler so myclass seemed to be the wrong place for the friend declarations.  (As krsteeve notes myClassImpl would be wrong too as the members are public.)